# Its not showing options to choose any one dialer after pressing dialer, if devise contain more than one dialer

Tags: android

Is there any ways to explicitly pop-up a dialog to showing options to select any one dialer if the devise contain more than one dialer app.

```
<intent-filter> 
<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
<action android:name="android.intent.action.DIAL" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
```

I had given above lines in manifest file for an activity, it works fine in Motorola Atrix and Samsung Nexes S but not in Motorola Mildstone, Galaxy ACE.
Can any one help.